# Custom Post type category pages template and loop

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, custom-taxonomy, loop, taxonomy

I have a custom post type by the name of the event.

So Created a category page them for them like this →

```
category-event.php
```

Like this →

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
//and then the loop here
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

But the individual category pages are not generating the posts only from those categories, but entirely all posts.

I think something needs to be fixed in the loop?

## Update → the Loop

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type' => 'event',
        'posts_per_page' => 10,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        )  );
    ?>
<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <!-- the loop -->
    <div class="class1">
    <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="class2">
            <div class="class3">
                <?php $url = esc_url( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'video_oembed', true ) ); ?>
                <?php $embed = wp_oembed_get( $url ); ?>
                <div class="class4">
                    <iframe id="class_frame" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/watch"); ?>" allowfullscreen frameborder="0"></iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="class6">
                <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
    </div>
    <!-- end of the loop -->
    <!-- <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?> -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: well, post the loop then ;) the way i see it, you don't use the main query, but create a new one. and that will not contain the main queries argument, unless you also put 'em in there, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may alter the main query before the loop, but it's crucial to reset the main query afterwards. Otherwise you'll probably run into problems elsewhere.

Disclaimer: Doing this is officially discouraged by WordPress [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/query_posts/). However, in my experience it works perfectly to achieve the behaviour you want. Just don't forget to add **wp_reset_query();** after closing the loop.

```
<?php query_posts('post_type=event'); ?>
  <?php if ( have_posts() ): while ( have_posts() ): the_post(); ?>

    <!-- Stuff happening inside the loop -->

  <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

**Another approach** (slightly more complicated but without altering the main query) would be:

```
<?php $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'post_type' => 'event', 'post_status' => 'publish' ); ?>
<?php $get_category_posts = get_posts( $args ); ?>
<?php foreach ( $get_category_posts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>

  <!-- Stuff happening inside our custom 'loop' -->

<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

According to the 2nd solution, **your PHP-File should look like this:**

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'post_type' => 'event', 'post_status' => 'publish' ); ?>
<?php $get_category_posts = get_posts( $args ); ?>
<?php foreach ( $get_category_posts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>

  <div class="class1">
    <div class="class2">
      <div class="class3">

        <?php print_r( get_post_meta( get_the_ID() ) ); // Just for demo purposes ?>

        <?php // $url = esc_url( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'video_oembed', true ) ); ?>
        <?php // $embed = wp_oembed_get( $url ); ?>

        <div class="class4">
          <iframe id="class_frame" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/watch" allowfullscreen frameborder="0"></iframe>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="class6">
        <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

If this doesn't work it might be that you're working in the wrong template file. Without knowing your project my guess would be that it should be **archive-event.php**

**Update:**

It turned out to be **taxonomy-event.php** in this case.

Comment: Doing this is officially discouraged by WordPress → Whats the alternative solution?

Comment: @TheWPNovice See the alternative approach I've just added to my original answer.

Comment: hi @Nico :) nope. i wouldn't go that route eather. actually you are calling the main query here, but then you never use it. i'd rather alter the main query (if ever there is a need for) via `pre_get_posts`..

Comment: @honk31 You're right. I removed the unnecessary loop. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @TheWPNovice I think you're either getting mixed up between different solutions or working inside the wrong template-file. Try copying the "your PHP-File should look like this"-Part I've added to my answer into your PHP-File. If it's the correct file it should work as expected. If your website is _not_ showing the get_post_meta-Array afterwards, you're in the wrong file.

Comment: `taxonomy-event.php` worked for me. Please highlight this in your answers so that future users will benefit from this.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to make use of the template hierarchy. So, according to the information given of your custom post type, the name of the category template should be: category-event.php

Sure, you also need to have the right query in place (in your "category-event.php" file) in order to get the correct posts.

```
// Custom Query for CPT 'tires'
$custom_arguments = array(
    'post_type' => 'event',
    'posts_per_page' => '36',
    'taxonomy' => 'your-event-categories',
    'orderby'=> 'name',
    'order'=> 'ASC'
);
$loop = new WP_Query($custom_arguments);

$html = '';
// Build your HTML output
$html .= '<div class="event-archive">';
    while ($loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
        $html .= Your HTML Markup to display the content
        $html .= '<div class="gridbox">';

        endwhile;
        ....
        wp_reset_query();
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: so this is the clue → ` wp_reset_query();`

Comment: What do you mean by clue? As Nico also mentioned, it is important to reset the query variable to empty / reset the query. You should check the custom arguments in first place, if they are correct.

Comment: I have done it like this → https://www.screencast.com/t/b5wRjyhQC But the issue is it is still fetching all the posts not just of that category.

Comment: None of the solutions are currently working. the individual category pages are pulling posts from all the categories not just one.

Answer (score 2):

The problem of yours is, you run your own query, and make no use of the main `$wp_query`. try to use that one:

```
<?php
if ( have_posts() ) :
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        //whatever 
    endwhile;
endif;
```

and NOT

```
$the_query->have_posts()
```

Comment: `category-event.php` → the event category pages will take this template?

Comment: if you have a category with the slug event, and your events are in there, then yes. install this plugin: `Show Current Template` and visit the page you are talking about. it will name all currently used template files in the admin-bar